# Почему бот не удаляет приватный канал после его создания?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Я написал это для себя чтобы был бот который создаёт канал не в самом конце а после какого-то канала.
В итоге канал создаётся но не удаляется после выхода

Код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
        if after.channel.id == 778594516969586720:
            for guild in bot.guilds:
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=778594516856733696) #категория создания канала
                channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(
                    f'╠╣{member.display_name}', #название канала
                    position=3, #позиция созданного канала (для теста просто уберите этот пункт)
                    category=maincategory, #категория  в которой создастся канал
                    bitrate=96000 # установить битрейт 96
                )
                await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, move_members=True, manage_channels=True) # установить права на канал его создателю
                await member.move_to(channel2) # переместить пользователя в этот канал
#часть кода которая должна удалять канал после выхода но этого не делает
                def check(x, y):
                    return len(channel2.members) == 0
                await bot.wait_for('voice_channel_update', check = check)
                await channel2.delete()
```

Хз зачем но вот: [документация по discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check(x, y, z):
    return len(channel2.members) == 0

await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
await channel2.delete()
```